# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 3057 Incorrect user-level lock name on re indexing

Tags: database, magento-enterprise, reindex

When I run `php indexer.php --reindexall` command I get following error.

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 3057 Incorrect user-level lock name 'magento_prod.index_process_024cd255-917a-11e9-8262-3bda9350d94f'. in /var/www/html/bradywarehouse/production/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento/production/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/magento/production/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/magento/production/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/magento/production/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/magento/production/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT IS_USED_...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/magento/production/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT IS_USED_...', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/magento/production/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php(83): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT IS_USED_...', Array)
#7 /var/www/html/magento/production/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Lock/Storage/Db.php(96): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4->isLocked('magento_prod....')
#8 /var/www/html/magento/production/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Lock.php(257): Mage_Index_Model_Lock_Storage_Db->isLockExists('magento_prod....')
#9 /var/www/html/magento/production/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Lock.php(227): Mage_Index_Model_Lock->_isLockExistsDb('index_process_0...')
#10 /var/www/html/magento/production/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(480): Mage_Index_Model_Lock->isLockExists('index_process_0...', NULL)
#11 /var/www/html/magento/production/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(184): Mage_Index_Model_Process->isLocked()
#12 /var/www/html/magento/production/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#13 /var/www/html/magento/production/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#14 /var/www/html/magento/production/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#15 {main}

Next Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 3057 Incorrect user-level lock name 'magento_prod.index_process_024cd255-917a-11e9-8262-3bda9350d94f'., query was: SELECT IS_USED_LOCK(?); in /var/www/html/magento/production/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento/production/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
```

I am running Magento Enterprise edition 1.14.3.1 and MySQL version 5.7.26

How can I fix it ?

Comment: please review this https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-1-x/Cannot-reindex-Category-Products-Index-Process-Information/td-p/1603

Comment: @Shorabh already checked did not help.